# Submitting Select value with ajax.beginform on mvc4

Tags: c#, ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

It seems that my view isn't reaching my controller, I'm populating a select looping a model in the view and then I try to call an partial view with new info

My `HomeController.cs` has this method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusquedaDeSensores(int id)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "text...";
    retail2Entities cl = new retail2Entities();
    List<GetSensorByClient_Result> sensores = cl.GetSensorByClient(id,0).ToList();
    return PartialView("_BusquedaDeSensores",sensores);
}
```

This is what I have on my index page preloading some data and trying to send the selected value to my controller.

```
<ol class="round">
<li class="one">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BusquedaDeSensores", "Home", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "busquedaDeSensores" }))
{ 
<select id="Cientes" name="Clientes">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
   <option value="@item.idClient">@item.name</option> 
   }
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}

</li>

<li id="busquedaDeSensores "class="two">
lel
</li>
```

This would be my partial view `_BusquedaDeSensores`:

```
@model IEnumerable< Recnons.Models.GetSensorByClient_Result>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EntradaSalida", "Home", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post", LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader", UpdateTargetId = "entradaSalida" }))
{ 
<select id="Sensores" name="Sensores">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
   <option value="@item.Id">@item.Id</option> 
   }
    </select>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: are you sure that you are passing the value to?
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusquedaDeSensores(int id)
{}
i dindn't see any hidden or tag with name="id",  in your select the name is "Clientes" so, you should change the name in your controller to "Clientes" 
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult BusquedaDeSensores(int Clientes)
{}
or change the name in your view <select id="Cientes" name="id">

Comment: and since your controller is expecting a parameter and when you do the post MVC is not finding any parameter that match with "id", that's why your view is not reaching your controller

Comment: Thank you very much! that solves it, i knew it was something i was ignoring!

Comment: The id now DOES reach the controller but the ajax function isnt returning the new select, i should get into that